# Measuring upload speed in python

Tags: python, upload

Suppose, I am uploading a file using `HTTP` connection(`POST`) and the file is quite large. Is there any way to find the upload speed?

To be specific, I want to upload the file to ***Mediafire***.

Answer (score 0):

[Speedometer](http://excess.org/speedometer/) will help you in monitoring the speed/progress of a file transfer.